# I have a variable error and was curious to see if it's due to piecewise functions?

Tags: functions, parametric-functions, piecewise

So I have a displacement function sigx as a function of "t" (time) and sig.pre (pre-stress).  At some time "dx": force "fo" goes to 0, and the same displacement function now needs the current position and velocity as initial conditions to ensure continuity.  Though any time I test values equal to or above the time "dx" (I know I know, it should be dt) I receive an error of "General: 0.00#' is not a valid variable."  Below is my code, any advice?

```
velx[t_, σpre_] = D[(1/(m*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω^2))*(kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + σpre/2000000000000) + 
      Piecewise[{{fo, t <= dx}}, 0])*(Sqrt[1 - η^2] - (Sqrt[1 - η^2]*Cos[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω] + 
        η*Sin[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω])/E^(t*η*ω)) + 
    (((η*ω*((kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + km)))/(ω*Sqrt[1 - η^2]))*
       Sin[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t] + ((kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + km))*
       Cos[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t])/E^(η*ω*t), t]

sigx[t_, σpre_] := (1/(m*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω^2))*(kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + σpre/2000000000000) + 
     Piecewise[{{fo, t <= dx}}, 0])*(Sqrt[1 - η^2] - (Sqrt[1 - η^2]*Cos[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω] + 
       η*Sin[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω])/E^(t*η*ω)) + 
   (((Piecewise[{{velx[t, σpre], t >= dx}, {0, True}}] + 
        η*ω*((kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + km)))/(ω*Sqrt[1 - η^2]))*
      Sin[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t] + ((kb*xb + km*(0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + km))*
      Cos[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t])/E^(η*ω*t)

sigx[0.001, 10000000] - xb

sigx[0.004, 10000000] - xb
```

Below are assignments for constants:

```
xe = (kb*xb + km*xm)/(kb + km); 
ω = Sqrt[(kb + km)/m]; 
xm = 0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13; 
dx = 0.002; 
η = 0.1; 
ζ = 0.0625; 
m = 162; 
fo = 2.259*10^7; 
kb = 1.33*10^9; 
km = 6.893*10^9; 
xb = 0.0762; 
Sy = 1020000000; 
Δy = 0.000385; 
σpre = 10000000;
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Constants

```
xe = (kb*xb + km*xm)/(kb + km);
ω = Sqrt[(kb + km)/m];
xm = 0.0762 + (5*σpre)/10^13 // Rationalize;
dx = 0.002 // Rationalize;
η = 0.1 // Rationalize;
ζ = 0.0625 // Rationalize;
m = 162;
fo = 2.259*10^7 // Rationalize;
kb = 1.33*10^9 // Rationalize;
km = 6.893*10^9 // Rationalize;
xb = 0.0762 // Rationalize;
Sy = 1020000000;
Δy = 0.000385 // Rationalize;
σpre = 10000000;
```

Functions

```
velx[t_, σpre_] = 
 D[(1/(m*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω^2))*(kb*xb + 
       km*(762/10000 + σpre/2000000000000) + 
       Piecewise[{{fo, t <= dx}}, 0])*(Sqrt[
        1 - η^2] - (Sqrt[1 - η^2]*
           Cos[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω] + η*
           Sin[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω])/
        E^(t*η*ω)) + (((η*ω*((kb*xb + 
                km*(762/10000 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + 
                km)))/(ω*Sqrt[1 - η^2]))*
        Sin[
         Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*
          t] + ((kb*xb + km*(762/10000 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb +
             km))*Cos[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t])/
     E^(η*ω*t), t] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
sigx[t_, σpre_] = (1/(m*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω^2))*(kb*
       xb + km*(762/10000 + σpre/2000000000000) + 
      Piecewise[{{fo, t <= dx}}, 0])*(Sqrt[
       1 - η^2] - (Sqrt[1 - η^2]*
          Cos[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω] + η*
          Sin[t*Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω])/
       E^(t*η*ω)) + (((Piecewise[{{velx[t, σpre], 
              t >= dx}, {0, 
              True}}] + η*ω*((kb*xb + 
                km*(762/10000 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + 
                km)))/(ω*Sqrt[1 - η^2]))*
       Sin[
        Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*
         t] + ((kb*xb + km*(762/10000 + (5*σpre)/10^13))/(kb + 
           km))*Cos[Sqrt[1 - η^2]*ω*t])/
    E^(η*ω*t) // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
sigx[10^-3, 10000000] - xb // Simplify // N

(* 0.00172049 *)

sigx[4*^-3, 10000000] - xb // Simplify // N

(* 4.19129*10^-6 *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[sigx[t, 10000000] - xb,
 {t, 0, 25*^-4},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Was there a particular order they needed to be evaluated in?  Or was the // Rationalize all I needed for it to properly register?  There must be something wrong still though with my code since the problem is still discontinuous after fo drops off.

Comment: With v12.3.1 on a Mac, your code gives the same results as mine. I   guessed that perhaps you were having precision issues and structured my code to control the precision in case that was your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I'll run it and see if I can get the continuity to fix from there.  That error was preventing testing, so thank you!